# Forcing .NET to use assembly alongside application instead of GAC

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, gac

I'm developing a .NET application. The application uses a managed library. The application only works with a specific version of this library.

Currently I'm including a copy of the library's DLL files alongside the application. This works fine if the user does not have the library installed. The problem is, if the user has another version of the library installed, the application uses that version instead of the one included alongside the application.

How can I disable or override this behaviour? I've tried Googling it and the only answers that I've found seem to either relate to unmanaged assemblies or refer to specifying a path for a library that isn't installed.

EDIT: I did some more investigation and it turns out that the two versions of the library have the same version number and public key token, so there's no way for the system to distinguish between them. So basically I need to force the system to use the supplied version instead of the version in the GAC, even if it thinks they're the same.

Comment: That is not how .NET works, it will only ever use a DLL from the GAC when there is an **exact** version match.  Do make sure you don't have a bindingRedirect in the app.config file.  And make sure that the author actually changed the [AssemblyVersion] and not, say, the file version.  You're screwed if he did that.

Comment: I don't have a binding redirect, and I can confirm that the system is certainly using the one from the GAC instead of the one next to the application. I am fairly certain that the library's assembly version is in fact different, is there any way to confirm this?

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.  Log all binds so you can see the decisions that the CLR made.  Post the trace in your question if it looks like Greek to you.

Comment: It turns out that they have the same version number even though they're different.

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting the *Specific Version* of the reference to *true*.

You can set that property on the property pane of the reference to the assembly.

Comment: That only plays a role at compile-time.